# Decide enum storage which is uploaded to the server and shared by a Client app and an API

Tags: android, ios, database, asp.net-web-api, n-tier-architecture

**Technology stack**: One REST API developed in .Net Core 3.1. Two client apps one in Android and other in iOS

**Scenario**: Store enum value in the database such that when the data is uploaded to the API it makes sense (API can take decisions based on the enum).

> **Option 1**: Store enum as a number and copy it in the API.

*In this scenario, the enum value would be saved in the DB and transferred to the API. When the API need to use the enum for a condition or some other use, it would use the **copy of the enum** present in the API.*

**Pros**: No extra handling.

**Cons**: Have to maintain enum in API. If a new value is added in the enum on the client side then the API would have to be changed and published again **(The whole SDLC lifecycle)**.

> **Option 2**: Store enum as a number and add a table for each enum in the API.

*In this scenario, the enum value would be saved in the DB and transferred to the API. When the API need to use the enum for a condition or some other use, it would get the info of the **enum from its table** present in the API.*

**Pros**: No need to change API code when a new value is added in the enum.

**Cons**: Extra DB call to get enum value. Many small tables for each enum.

> **Option 3**: Store enum as a number and add an enum table for all the enums in the API.

*In this scenario, all the enums value would be saved in the single table of the DB and transferred to the API. When the API need to use the enum for a condition or some other use, it would get the info of the **enum from the enums table** present in the API.*

**Pros**: No need to change API code when a new value is added in the enum. No need to add new tables when a new enum is introduced.

**Cons**: Extra DB call to get enum value. String comparison.

> **Option 4**: Store enum as a string and transfer string value to the API.

*In this scenario, the enum would be saved as a string. When the API need to use the enum for a condition, it would simply use string comparison.*

**Pros**: No need to change API code when a new value is added in the enum. No need to make extra DB call for enums.

**Cons**: String comparison?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "in the API"? What sort of API is this anyway - REST? gRPC? Something else? (Different API protocols may or may not allow enums to be specified in the schema.)

Comment: It is a .Net Core 3.1 API. I will update the question

Comment: ".NET Core 3.1" is not an API protocol. It's a platform you can run all kinds of things on. We can't tell from that how or if you're defining the API in some way that means you generate the clients for Android and iOS, etc.

Comment: I did not know that .Net Core API supports other protocols. Anyway, I am developing a REST API using the HTTPS protocol and JSON for data transmission. I can easily serialize/deserialize enums from JSON. I am capable of handling enums as numbers as well as string. The question is about how to handle it in a way that requires less maintenance and standard practice.

Comment: To answer your first question my REST API allows defining enums in the DTOs.

Comment: Well if it's naturally an enum, and whatever tooling you're using allows you to define that enum, then it makes sense to do so.

Comment: @JonSkeet My question was about storage rather than the transmission of the enum. For e.g. If I store the Enum as a number in the DB then it would not make any sense in the API. In this case either I have to replicate the Enum in the API which would lead to API change and publish when new values are added in the Enum or store them as strings.

Comment: CONTD. If I store the Enum as a table then there would be many small tables in the API. So my question was "How do people store and manage enums?"

Comment: Please read my question with the storage concern in mind I hope then it would make more sense.

Comment: Please *edit the question* rather than adding multiple comments. If the question isn't clear enough already, you should always edit it rather than just commenting. Someone should be able to understand the question without reading the comments. I don't have time to get back to this now, but I'll have a look later - by which time hopefully the question will be clearer.

Comment: @JonSkeet I have refactored the question. Hopefully, it makes sense now. Review whenever you are free.

Comment: Okay, having looked now, I suspect this will be closed as opinion-based. It's not really a clear-cut programming question, and you already have a bunch of the pros/cons. (I would suggest thinking about what "adding an enum values" means in general though - I would *expect* that to be a change in the published API, and all servers and clients. It would be odd for only some parts of the code to know about it.)